# overflow-y is affecting overflow-x

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want the left column (#left) to have `overflow-y: scroll` and `overflow-x: visible`. However, the `overflow-x` ends up being scroll when I test it despite the code saying different. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").click(function(){
        $("#title").hide();
    });
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("#one").addClass("open");
        $("#oneBottom").addClass("clicked");
        
        $("#two").removeClass("open");
        $("#twoBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#three").removeClass("open");
        $("#threeBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#four").removeClass("open");
        $("#fourBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#five").removeClass("open");
        $("#fiveBottom").removeClass("clicked");
    });
    
    $("#two").click(function(){
        $("#two").addClass("open");
        $("#twoBottom").addClass("clicked");
        
        $("#one").removeClass("open");
        $("#oneBottom").removeClass("clicked"); 
        
        $("#three").removeClass("open");
        $("#threeBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#four").removeClass("open");
        $("#fourBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#five").removeClass("open");
        $("#fiveBottom").removeClass("clicked");
    });
    
    $("#three").click(function(){
        $("#three").addClass("open");
        $("#threeBottom").addClass("clicked");
        
        $("#one").removeClass("open");
        $("#oneBottom").removeClass("clicked"); 
        
        $("#two").removeClass("open");
        $("#twoBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#four").removeClass("open");
        $("#fourBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#five").removeClass("open");
        $("#fiveBottom").removeClass("clicked");
    });
    
    $("#four").click(function(){
        $("#four").addClass("open");
        $("#fourBottom").addClass("clicked");
        
        $("#one").removeClass("open");
        $("#oneBottom").removeClass("clicked"); 
        
        $("#two").removeClass("open");
        $("#twoBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#three").removeClass("open");
        $("#threeBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#five").removeClass("open");
        $("#fiveBottom").removeClass("clicked");
    });
    
    $("#five").click(function(){
        $("#five").addClass("open");
        $("#fiveBottom").addClass("clicked");
        
        $("#one").removeClass("open");
        $("#oneBottom").removeClass("clicked"); 
        
        $("#two").removeClass("open");
        $("#twoBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#three").removeClass("open");
        $("#threeBottom").removeClass("clicked");
        
        $("#four").removeClass("open");
        $("#fourBottom").removeClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

```css
.open{
    margin-left: 124% !important;
    margin-top: 18% !important;
    width: 187% !important;
    height: 80% !important;
    font-size: 250% !important;
}
.clicked{
    border: red solid 3px !important; 
}
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
#title{
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
#left{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: visible;
}
#right{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 30%;
    border-left: solid 2px black;
}
.card{
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: grey solid 2px;
}
.first{
    margin-top: 6.5%;
}
#one{
    background-color: green;
}
.second{
    margin-top: 50%;
}
#two{
    background-color: green;
}
.third{
    margin-top: 93%;
}
#three{
    background-color: green;
}
.fourth{
    margin-top: 136%;
}
#four{
    background-color: green;
}
.fith{
    margin-top: 179%;
}
#five{
    background-color: green;
}
#main{
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: grey solid 3px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="title">
   <h1>Blah Blah Blah</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
   <div class="card first" id="oneBottom">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Heljaldf</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card first" id="one">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Heljaldf</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="card second" id="twoBottom">
    <h1>Sup</h1>
   </div>   
   <div class="card second" id="two">
    <h1>Sup</h1>
   </div>

   <div class="card third" id="threeBottom">
   </div>
   <div class="card third" id="three">
   </div>

   <div class="card fourth" id="fourBottom">
   </div>
   <div class="card fourth" id="four">
   </div>

   <div class="card fith" id="fiveBottom">
   </div>
   <div class="card fith" id="five">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
   <div id="main">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code doesn't say different, it's doing exactly what it's been told. I can't see an error anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're having with #left is that you're mixing visible with scroll. Because you're mixing values it's going to treat visible as auto instead.

Check out the W3 documentation on this here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapse-scroll

Comment: @humble.rumble Because it says so in the specs. James should have used a link to [the official W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapse-scroll) where it says __"some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’."__

Comment: Apologies. I didn't know that page even existed. I'm just speaking from my own experience.